# How to access user input (POST) in different Django views

Tags: python, django, forms, input

I have a view called "search" which stores POST input as "search_id" but "search_id" is only available in the scope of the view "search". I want to be able to access the variable "search_id" in my view "dispTable".

Disclaimer- if this part of my question makes no sense, plz ignore: I understand that I could add an additional parameter to dispTable which would allow me to pass the search_id into dispTable in a return statement but what if I wanted to be able to access search_id in multiple views.

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' :
        search_id = request.POST.get('textfield', None)            
        try:
            return dispTable(request)                
        except Person.DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponse("no such user")                
        except Person.MultipleObjectsReturned :
            #return dispTable(request, search_id)
            return showResults(request)                
    else :
         return render(request, 'People/search.html')

def dispTable(request) :
    table = authTable(Person.objects.filter(MAIN_AUTHOR = 'search_id'))
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    #return render(request, 'People/tableTemp.html', {'table':table}) 
    return render(request, 'People/tableTemp.html', {"table" : Person.objects.filter(MAIN_AUTHOR = search_id)})
```

I also tried using a form, but I still did not know how to access the input variable in additional views, like dispTable

```
from django import forms

class SearchForm(forms.Form) :
    search_id = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    def process(self) :
        search_id = self.cleaned_data['search_id']

def search(request) :
    if request.method == 'POST' :
        form = SearchForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() :
            form.process()                
        return dispTable(request)
    else :
        form = SearchForm()
    return render (request, 'People/search.html')
```

And here is my html file:

```
<form method="POST" action="send/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="textfield">
    <button type="submit">Upload text</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Why don't you use session?

Comment: I've never used sessions. Would that be an intuitive/ easy way to store user input to be used in multiple views?

Comment: Since you want to exchange information between views then sessions is your solution :)